# Get cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension and i need to get `PHPSESSID` from cookies.

When I type `document.cookie` in console I get the cookies of the page but not `PHPSESSID`
but when i open [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) the PHPSESSID is shown:

[image: Console + EditThisCookie]

How can I get the PHPSESSID value?

I tried

```
function getPHPSESSID() {
  var url = tab.url;
  chrome.cookies.get({"url": url, "name": 'PHPSESSID'}, function(cookie) {
    alert(cookie.value);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Issue

Your problem here is that you probably aren't using the correct permissions. To get cookies from a certain url/page you'll need to use the `chrome.cookies` API. This API needs the **permissions for `"cookies"` and all the URLs you want to retrieve cookies from**.

### Solution

In your `manifest.json`, **request the permissions you need**. If you want to retrieve cookies from all the sites, you can use the `"<all_urls>"` permission. Or, if you want cookies only from that site you can use, for example, `"http://luptaonline.com/*`. I also noticed that you are using the `chrome.tabs` API, so the permissions in `manifest.json` should look like this:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
],
...
```

Now, in your `background.js`, you can easily call the `chrome.cookies.get()` method to **retrieve the `PHPSESSID` cookie, like this**:

```
var myUrl = "http://luptaonline.com/player/"; // assuming that this is the url

chrome.cookies.get({url: myUrl, name: 'PHPSESSID'}, function(cookie) {
    // do something with the cookie
    console.log(cookie);
    alert(cookie.name + ' found, value: ' + cookie.value);
});
```

---

Running the above code you'll get what you want. Here are some screenshot of the results:

Console log:

[image: log]

Cookie alert:

[image: alert]

### Working example

You can download a working example of the extension **[HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/totvashuyo25y77/extension-26451377.zip)**.

### Documentation

You may find this documentation links helpful:

- [`chrome.cookies` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies)
- [`chrome.cookies.get` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-get)